# Как отслеживать состояние подключения к сети?

Tags: java, android

нужна помощь и желательно объяснение по поводу цикла и булеана. Язык java. Мобильная разработка.
есть вот такой код, его задача проверять есть ли подключение к инету или нет. Нашел такой код:

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

И теперь мне нужно его связать с циклом с пред условием.
Проверяем есть ли интернет, если да то заново проверяем. Если нету то выводим уведомление.
Сам начал заниматься программированием недавно, поэтому много не знаю.

Answer (score 4):

Такой цикл приведёт к интенсивному нагреву устройства и расходу батареи. Чтобы эффективно проверять наличие интернета, надо подписаться на событие изменения доступности сети и в его обработчике выполнять проверку:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<receiver android:name="NetworkChangeReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**NetworkUtil.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class NetworkUtil {
    public static final int TYPE_WIFI = 1;
    public static final int TYPE_MOBILE = 2;
    public static final int TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED = 0;

    public static int getConnectivityStatus(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (null != activeNetwork) {
            if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
                return TYPE_WIFI;

            if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
                return TYPE_MOBILE;
        } 
        return TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED;
    }

    public static String getConnectivityStatusString(Context context) {
        int conn = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(context);
        String status = null;
        if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_WIFI) {
            status = "Wifi enabled";
        }
        else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_MOBILE) {
            status = "Mobile data enabled";
        }
        else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED) {
            status = "Not connected to Internet";
        }
        return status;
    }
}
```

**NetworkChangeReceiver.java**

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int status = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(context);
        if(status == NetworkUtil.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED) {
            // Действия при недоступности сети
        }
        else {
            // Действия при доступности сети
        }
    }
}
```

И не стоит забывать, что доступность сети ещё не означает доступности ресурсов, поэтому стоит добавить проверку на подключение к необходимым адресам.